# Odd PHP Class autoloader Behavior - PEAR Related

Tags: php, pear, autoloader

I have a strange problem I can't figure out.  I'm using `PEAR` to send mail from a PHP page.  The `Send_Mail` class is working (sending mail using SMTP), but I'm getting this strange warning associated with my `autoloader`.

```
Warning: include(classes/LOGIN.php) 
[<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\initialize.php on line 46`
```

In my `initialize.php` file, I have this:

```
function autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('autoloader');
```

And in my `header.php` file I am loading several PHP classes for the site:

```
// autoload PHP classes for site
autoloader('Navigation');
autoloader('Validation');
```

The error referes to a LOGIN class which I don't have.  But I searched my entire site folder, including `php` and found these two lines in `C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php`:

```
/* These standard authentication methods are always available. */
$this->setAuthMethod('LOGIN', array($this, '_authLogin'), false);
$this->setAuthMethod('PLAIN', array($this, '_authPlain'), false);
```

When I comment out the line containing `LOGIN` I get the same warning but for `PLAIN` and when I comment out both lines, the warnings go away (but then SMTP authentication fails).

Why is this happening?

**UPDATE**

Here is my new `autoloader`:

```
function autoloader($class) {

    if (file_exists('classes' . $class . '.php')) {
        include 'classes' . $class . '.php'; 
    }
}
```

When I echo `'classes' . $class . '.php'`, though, I get this:

`classes/.php`

And then if I change it back to not use the `file_exists` it works, but the `echo` still shows `classes/.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted back to a simple `autoloader` and things seem to be working fine:

```
function autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('autoloader');
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of Net_SMTP you're on, but the `setAuthMethod` function takes as a parameter various different types of structures - method names, classes, objects, callables, etc.

Since PHP is dynamically typed, `SMTP.php` in Net_SMTP has to do a lot of checking on that object in order to determine what type of object it is. As part of that, it tries to determine if 'LOGIN' is a class name, which is invoking your autoloader.

The solution is to perform a `file_exists` in your autoloader before trying the include, but of course if your include path is complex in any way you're basically setting yourself up for headaches. Anyone who has dealt with writing a comprehensive autoloader knows your pain.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I've fiddled with this a bit, and of course am already running into those headaches you spoke about...  Darn ;-)  For some reason with a simple autoloader, I'm getting unexpected results.  I've updated my question if you could take a look.